# GAMS optimazation using MIP: Stuck in a local minima. What can I do

Tags: gams-math

I have a minimization problem where I don't get optimal solution through `MIP`. I am wondering how to fix my problem. It might have been stuck in local minimum.**What can I do?**

I have also considered to change the tolerenance. **How do I change the tolerance?**

```
Solve MyMode Minimizing y using MIP
*Not getting optimal solution
```

Comment: I have looked here but didn't find the answer: https://www.gams.com/latest/docs/S_CPLEX.html#CPLEX_miptol

Answer (score 0):

You can use optcr=0 option to force gams finding the global optimal solution 
additionally, you can give it a better initial solution using x.l=5 (for example)